# JSF template: missing layout

Tags: jsf

I'm very new to JSF and I have some problem using JSF template. The code of the template newTemplate.xhtml) looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link href="./resources/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="./resources/css/cssLayout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title><ui:insert name="title">Default title</ui:insert></title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div id="top">
            <ui:insert name="top">Top</ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="left">
                <ui:insert name="left">Left</ui:insert>
                <h:form>
                    <h:commandButton id="test" value="Test" action="/jsf/newTemplateClient.xhtml"/>
                </h:form>
            </div>
            <div id="content" class="left_content">
                <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">
            <ui:insert name="bottom">Bottom</ui:insert>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Start page called index1.xhtml looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <body>
        <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/newTemplate.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="title">
                TEST
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </body>
</html>
```

Finally template client page (called newTemplateClient.xhtml):

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/newTemplate.xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   <ui:define name="content">
        Some content in newTemplateClient.xhtml
   </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Here is the behaviour of the application:

1. Application starts (address bar says localhost:8080/WebTEST/) and the layout and content is displayed properly,
2. I click on the 'Test' button and the content of newTemplateClient.xhtml is also displayed properly (address changes to: localhost:8080/WebTEST/faces/index1.xhtml),
3. I click again 'Test' button and the content is displayed but I loose the layout like there is no css style applied (no colors and formatting). Now the address bar says: localhost:8080/WebTEST/faces/jsf/newTemplateClient.xhtml

The template file is located in WEB-INF folder, the newTemplateClient.xhtml is located in jsf folder.

I know it's probably some simple thing but I really ran out of ideas what might be the cause of this problem.

Comment: The problem is the relative link resolves to a different absolute URL after you leave the index page. Consider using `<h:outputStylesheet library="css" value="default.css">` instead of `<link href=...>`.

Comment: @DanielLyons I've added <h:outputStylesheet library="css" value="default.css" name="default.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" value="cssLayout.css" name="cssLayout.css"></h:outputStylesheet> and it works! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Awesome! :) I've made it an answer. If you could accept it, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat my comment, the problem is that the relative URL in the CSS links resolves to a different absolute URL after you leave the index page. However, there is a nice JSF tag you can use instead of the raw link to solve your problem: use `<h:outputStylesheet library="css" value="default.css">` instead of `<link href=...>`.